# On How to prove that any point in a closed interval $[x_0, x_1]$ can be written as $t(x_1) + (1-t)x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that the segment that unites two points $(x_0,y_0), (x_1,y_1)$ in $R^2$ is given by the points  $\{ t(x_1,y_1) + (1-t) (x_0,y_0) | 0 \le t \le 1 \}$.

My professor suggested to use the properties of triangles that are similar between each other, but first I feel like I would need to prove that any point in a closed interval $[x_0, x_1]$ can be written as $t(x_1) + (1-t)x_0$ with $t \in [0,1]$. How would I do this?

Comment: Say $x\in[x_0,x_1]$ and $x=tx_1+(1-t)x_0$. Solve for $t$, then show $t\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know a bit of analysis,

Let $f(t)=tx_1 + (1-t)x_0$ where $x_0\le x_1$ and $t\in [0,1]$.

$f'(t)=x_1-x_0 \ge 0$, so $f$ is differentiable with $f' \ge 0$ and so hence continuous.

Then $f(0)=x_0$, $f(1)=x_1$ so $x_0\le f \le x_1$ and since $f$ is continuos and $[0,1]$ is connected, its image is connected so $f([0,1])=[x_0,x_1]$ (or this can be deduced by Intermediate Value Theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that 
$$
\forall x \in [x_0,x_1] \Rightarrow t=\frac{x_0-x}{x_0-x_1} \in [0,1]
$$
and

$$
\forall t\in [0,1] \Rightarrow x_0\le x_0+t(x_1-x_0) \le x_1
$$

Answer (score 1):

We go for a straight line between $u_0 = (x_0, y_0)^t$ and $u_1 = (x_1, y_1)$. So it must have the equation
$$
u(t) = u_0 + t (u_1 - u_0) \quad (*)
$$
which is using $u_0$ as origin vector of the line and the difference vector $u_1 - u_0$ as direction vector $d$. $t$ is some scalar $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

We can insert $t = 0$ and get $u(0) = u_0$. Then we try $t = 1$ and see that $u(1) = u_0 + u_1 - u_0 = u_1$. Very nice.

Now an arbitrary vector $u$ from the segment between $u_0$ and $u_1$ as well is subject to equation $(*)$. The parameter $t$ measures how far in multiples of the direction vector $d$ that vector is from the origin vector $u_0$. So it must be between $t=0$ (at the origin vector) and $t=1$ (at $u_1$). E.g. the midpoint is characterized by $t=1/2$.

I am so used to this geometric / algebraic interpretation that I have difficulties to judge if that is already good enough as an argument or if we have to involve topological arguments if we are really sceptic (e.g. see the answer by user160738), e.g. if we want to disprove that the vector $u(t)$ with $t = 1/\pi$ might lie on the line but outside the connection segment.

If we accept $(*)$ and that the connection segment is characterized by parameters $t \in [0, 1]$ it is easy to transform into
$$
u(t) = u_0 + t (u_1 - u_0) = (1-t) u_0 + t u_1
$$